# Find all SQL tables & columns updated from a process

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, change-tracking

I am seeing if there is an efficient/fast way of finding all tables/columns updated from a specific process. Basically we want to know all SQL columns that are updated from a frontend ERP process.

I know of two ways - either enable Change Tracking on every single table which is not very efficient, or spin up a blank test environment, perform the process and do row counts on all tables then go and view the data.

Does anyone else have a better method than the two described above?

Comment: Why not use the profiler?

Comment: what is your sql server version?

Comment: O geez, I forgot about that tool.... basically I can set it up to trace all the queries executed by the ERP app right?...Then in test environment run single process and see all queries that were performed from that process

Comment: @jyao SQL 2012 Developer Edition